# Como consultar a base de dados da firebase atraves de uma pagina HTML ou PHP

Tags: php, java, html, firebase

tenho uma base de dados ja criado ja recebe dados  no firebase, esse mesmo dados são envia do meu App.
Á possibilidade de consultar esses mesmos dados no firebase através de uma pagina feita em HTML OU PHP

Comment: de acordo com a [documentação](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) é possivel sim.

Answer (score 0):

Quando uma duvida desse tipo surgir, não exite em consultar a domentação. Nela, geralmente é possivel saber quais plataformas/linguagens são suportadas. Nesse caso, de acordo com o guia de [instalação e configuração](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start?hl=pt-br) existem APIs de acesso em varias linguagens, incluindo o php. No caso especifico do PHP, a documentação de uso esta disponivel [aqui](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).